# entering data into a mysql database using php in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm currently trying to enter data from a form in a wordpress web page into a mysql database.

here is the code from the html page on wordpress

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] ?>" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="firstname" />
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

i have installed the phpexec plugin and that seems to be runing fine.

when i enter data in the form and i submit it doesnt appear in the database.

My primary key seems to auto increment telling me something happened but no data appears.

thanks in advance

Comment: Word of warning: this is a textbook example of how NOT to handle user-submitted data. I'd suggest reading up on SQL injection attacks.

Comment: What you're doing here is so hazardously bad you should delete this code before you do yourself some serious harm. Take the short amount of time it takes to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and you'll know how to do it correctly.

Comment: For one you don't have anything set to tell the code to only execute this when post is set. It will just add rows on load in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get a good book and be sure you're learning how to use MySQL and PHP correctly and securely, as per the above comments. See [Learning PHP and MySQL - O'Reilly Media](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596101107.do)

Comment: security is not a massive issue at the moment. I got this code from W3schools and was using it as a test. can somebody tell me how to tell this peice of code to execute when post is set.

Comment: W3schools is about the worst place to learn; the code you got from them is a good example.

Comment: songdogtech, thanks alot for your advice, however can you tell me tell me how to tell this peice of code to execute when post is set, please